# Creating an image_tag link to user_path in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Why do I keep getting an error here:

```
    <%= link_to image_tag user.photo.url(:watch), user_path(user) %>
```

Error: undefined method `symbolize_keys!' for "/users/4":String

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<%= link_to image_tag(user.photo.url(:watch)), user_path(user) %>
```